Can I get a new key cut without it being reprogrammed?
We have a 2011 Chevrolet Orlando.
A few weeks ago one of the keys snapped off:

Today, exactly the same thing has happened to our other key so the car is now stuck on the drive.
The fobs themselves still work to lock the car. My question is can I simply get a new key cut and swap over the internal electronics, or will it have to be reprogrammed?
I'm based in the UK, so I was hoping I could pop to somewhere like Timpson to have one cut for much cheaper rather than buy new paired keys.
Edit: photo showing the circuit board which looks like it can be swapped out to another key:

Update: Timpson were able to sort both keys for a fraction of the cost, £75 for the pair. They couldn't just replace the blade, it was a whole new shell. But they transferred the internals without any reprogramming being necessary.

Forgive my ignorance, but is the key a flip key with the fob built into it?

@Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 pretty sure it is for these

@Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 The key does flip out, but you can take apart the shell to expose the internals. I had to fix one of them once when the key was in the ignition and I sat on a lanyard attached to the key, breaking that flip out mechanism.

Just added a better picture of the internals, @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2

Why not just use the keys you still have? It doesn't look like they snapped, but came loose. You should be able to get them re-attached.

This has happened to me. From the picture the blade has not snapped but its housing in the fob had fractured. I was able to remove the blade from the ignition lock with thin-nosed pliers (ha – I even used the pilers to turn the blade and start the car, with the fob in proximity as also needed by the system). Skoda wanted £200 up-front for a new key. Timpsons supplied me with one for a fraction of that, including copying the electronic code.

Does your car have a proximity sensor in the key?  It may be enough to simply attach something as a handle to the exiting key shaft to make turning easier, and fasten the remainder of the fob to that with a split keyring.

@Criggie I don't know. I wasn't sure how the 'pairing' worked exactly, which is why I wasn't sure if there was anything special about the blade itself.

Yes you should be able to do this - you mentioned Timpsons, and it is probably worth visiting them before purchasing anything since they may be able to replace the blade itself or potentially replace the blade and enclosure and re-use your existing internals.

Thanks, I guess my question stems from not knowing what exactly is being 'paired', if it's purely the electronics or something special about the blade itself. The blade can be swapped out on the same fob, too. So potentially that's all is needed.

The blade is just cut to your lock barrel - which Timpsons should be able to do using your existing blade as it appears the break is well clear of the actual "key" part of the blade.

Yes, the blade hasn't snapped, but it's housing fractured. In my case the blade didn't fit Timpson's fob, so they cut a new one.
